# Project a boolean value with Spring from MongoDB depending on field existence

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to project a boolean value depending on the existence of a certain field in the document in MongoDB with Spring Framework.

Let's assume I have documents in my Mongo DB. Their structure looks like this (**testedField** may not exist):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("some object ID"),
    "field1": "some value",
    "field2": "another value",
    "testedField": "this field may be absent"
}
```

or like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("some object ID"),
    "field1": "some value",
    "field2": "another value"
}
```

And I also have a data class MyClass:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MyClass {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private boolean myBoolVal;
}
```

In my DAO, there is a method that projects values of its fields to the class:

```
public List<MyClass> findThings(Collection<ObjectId> ids) {
    Criteria criteria = where(ID).in(ids);
    Aggregation matchAndProject = newAggregation(
            match(criteria),
            project("field1", "field2")
                    .and("testedField").ne(null).as("myBoolVal"));
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(matchAndProject, "my_collection", MyClass.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

The idea is to have `true` in **myBoolVal** field if **testedField** exists, and `false` if it doesn't.

But the code above throws `IllegalArgumentException("Values must not be null!")`.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found the solution: it is enough to use just `when("fieldName")` with no `exists()` or `is(null)` etc.

```
public List<MyClass> findThings(Collection<ObjectId> ids) {
    Criteria criteria = where(ID).in(ids);
    Aggregation matchAndProject = newAggregation(
            match(criteria),
            project("field1", "field2")
                    .and(ConditionalOperators.when("testedField")
                        .then(true)
                        .otherwise(false))
                    .as("myBoolVal"));
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(matchAndProject, "my_collection", MyClass.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Comment: Dupilcate answer.

Comment: There is a significant difference between the answers that allows you to use the query with no MongoCommandException if you pay more attention. The method ```exists()``` leads to the mentioned exception, so you should avoid using it. That was in the comments section of the answer you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional projection using criteria

```
public List<MyClass> findThings(Collection<ObjectId> ids) {

    Cond condition = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("testedField")
        .exists(true))
        .then(true)
        .otherwise(false)
    ;
    Criteria criteria = where(ID).in(ids);
    Aggregation matchAndProject = newAggregation(
            match(criteria),
            project("field1", "field2")
                    and(condition).as("myBoolVal"));
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(matchAndProject, "my_collection", MyClass.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Comment: It ends up with:
```com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Unrecognized expression '$exists''```

Comment: Replace this code and try Cond condition = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("testedField")
        .is(null))
        .then(false)
        .otherwise(true) ;

Answer (score -1):

Why not `Boolean`? `true` if a field exists, `false` and `null` if not.

But in your case the field `myBoolVal` anything equals `false`. One thing - your fields are final, you cannot make any manipulations with them ... it's not correct to set entity fields as `final`.

Last thing: do you use Spring? It has a perfect library for working with mongodb and work with mongodb is very similar with jpa functionality.

Comment: The problem is in the aggregation itself: it does not allow the use of ```null``` in ```ne()``` method.

Comment: Those methods are from ```org.springframework.data.mongodb.core``` package of Spring.

Comment: In this case why is not your entity class annotated with `@Document`, `@Field`, no `@Id`? If you want to work with an object like with entity, male it the entity ))

Comment: Okay, but that still won't resolve the issue anyway.